# Spinner's Listener detects default/display choice as ItemSelected?

Tags: android, spinner, listener

I have an intent launched activity with a number of spinners on the page. I've just set up my spinner's ItemSelected listeners, following [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html) guide. The problem is, the first item in each Spinner is basically "Please select", just so it's not a blank box: so my ItemSelected Listener detects the fact that Please select is in the spinner and seems to assume that it was selected rather than loaded by default. Ideally I want the listener to only detect when an actual choice is made. What is the best way to ignore the default selection?

Here's the relevant code:

```
    ageSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ageSpinner);
    ageAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
    (this, R.array.ageArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    ageAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ageSpinner.setAdapter(ageAdapter);
    ageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) {
      Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The planet is " +
          parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

Comment: I moved your solution to its own community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the selection is done on the first layout phase. So the first time your layout is computed, the `Spinner` raises `onItemSelected`. Its quite annoying, but its the way it works. You could try a couple different things, but given you already have *Please Select Something* items, the best you could do is ignore the event when the selected item is 0.

Comment: Editing my main post to show my solution - thanks for the answer! (Exclude 0)

Answer (score 1):

Set a boolean to false, check it in the onItemSelected and if false, set it to true and do nothing else.  Next time, when it's true do as you normally would.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of approaches possible here. For example, you can override the normal behaviour of a `Spinner` using reflection, or simply switch to a `Button` imitating a `Spinner`, which on clicking on it pops up an `AlertDialog`.

However, other solutions can easier to implement. Barak has named one, while an alternative would be to simply check the selected position in the `Spinner`, assuming that "Please select" will always be the first item (and hence, at position `0`) and you're not doing any sorting on the items.

I'm sure you'll find one of the possibilities suitable for your problem, but perhaps you can also a elaborate a bit more on why exactly it's problematic `onItemSelected(...)` gets fired for the initial selection?

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) {
        if (pos != 0) {
        //this if makes sure it ignores 0, which is 
            //Please Select in the drop down    
      Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), parent.getTag().toString() +
          parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}
```